# I want to Accumulate resulting values, but can't initialize the variables to ZERO without falling in forbidden double assignment in VERILOG

Tags: verilog, fpga, accumulator

I have created a FSM which step by step calculates parts of an equation, then update the input and do it again many times. Now I wish to accumulate this results at every iteration.

Suppose val is the produced value and Zval is the sumatory of the successive values, I was trying to use a register like this

```
always @ (sum_val)
Zval = Zval + val;
```

and initialize like this

```
always @ (enable)
Zval = 0;
```

Quartus-II complaints that can't resolve multiply assignments.

If I don't initialize, during simulation, Zval get a don't care from the beginning, so val + a don't care produces a don't care also.

What should I do? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't you initialize it during reset?

Comment: Do you mean the reset state of the FSM? Problem is that I pass trough reset several time at every iteration. Putting the sumatory variable at zero like that would delete the previous result, while my intention is to add these results :S

Answer (score 3):

I think its very important to note that what Verilog can do in simulation is a very large superset of all the things you can do when describing hardware. For instance, the definition you provide for the `Zval` register will not in fact generate a register but instead some sort of flipflop on both edges of `sum_val` independent of any kind of clock. While such designs are possible, they fall into the realm of asynchronous design which is typically avoided due to its complexity. Doubly true for FPGA design as FPGAs typically assume you are making synchronous designs and do very poorly at implementing asynchronous systems. As such, your problem can be solved by simply constructing a synchronous register that Quartus will love and you will find easier to work with:

```
always @(posedge clk, negedge rst) begin
  if (~rst) begin
    Zval <= '0;
  end
  else begin
    if (sum_val) begin
      Zval <= Zval + val;
    end
  end
end
```

This is the typical form of a synchronous register (on `clk`) with an asynchronous reset `rst`. By connecting this to be pushbutton on the FPGA board, you can reset the system anytime you want, which will set `Zval` to 0. Note also the separate clauses for the asynchronous part (`Zval <= '0;`) and the synchronous part (the rest); always separate these clauses or the synthesis tool will generally create something strange.

Comment: This is very interesting. Excuse my ignorance.I have question. I have certainly implemented a "start" button in my system, would this be the same than "rst", so this everytime I press start system initialize the registers and the FSM to reset level. Or is that the "rst" is also necesary to implement aside the the start?

Comment: @sujeto1 It depends on how youve implemented your `start`, if its synchronous or asynchronous. If it is a synchronous `start`, youd need to add it to the else clause in the example above, making the body look like `if (start) begin Zval <= '0; end else if (sum_val) begin Zval <= Zval + val; end`. If your `start` is asynchronous, then it would be the same thing as `rst` in the example above and can be connected to it. Note however that in the example above, `rst` is asserted low, so a value of `1'b0` will reset the system and a value of `1'b1` will let the system run.